# Korean Language Support Missing from iPad Simulator

Tags: ipad, ios-simulator

I am running iPad simulator version 4.0 - and it appears as though it has no Korean language support.

Does anyone know why, or if there is a way to enable this?

I had Korean support in my iPhone app, and the simulator for that had the proper language support.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The iPad device also has no support for the Korean language. Just wait a few days and iOS 4.2 will be there, probably with Korean.

Comment: Not the answer I wanted, but... Thanks!

Comment: iOS 4.2 should come in a few days. Apple said November. Maybe it supports Korean, and if so, the new SDK will too.